# aws claudiajs bcrypt-nodejs

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda, bcryptjs

Tengo una aplicación en express usando **claudiajs** para facilitar el uso de AWS Lambda y API Gateway. Tengo un problema cuando ejecuto mi router en AWS Lambda me responde `502 Bad Gateway` y no logro encontrar el porque.

```
router.post('/register', asyncHandler(register), login);


async function register(req, res, next) {
    let user = await userCtrl.insert(req.body);
    user = user.toObject();
    delete user.hashedPassword;
    req.user = user;
    next()
}
```

controlador

```
async function insert(user) {
    try {
        user = await Joi.validate(user, userSchema, {abortEarly: false});
        const salt = bCrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        user.hashedPassword = bCrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
        delete user.password;
        return await new User(user).save();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw boom.boomify(e);
    }
}
```

Utilizando logs encontre que en esta linea en el controlador no responde ningún valor.

```
 user.hashedPassword = bCrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
 console.log(user.hashedPassword);
```

Estoy usando **bcrypt-nodejs**

Comment: Creo que el problema está en como usas la librería Joi, en particular el resultado del método `validate` no es `user`, es un objeto que contiene a `user`. Por lo tanto, `user.password` es `undefined` tal como lo tienes ahora, y es por eso que `bcrypt` no te devuelve un hash. Prueba con: `const result = await Joi.validate(user, userSchema, {abortEarly: false});`, luego debes hacer: `user = result.user;` y ya podrás continuar con lo demás igual. Prueba eso y comentas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras te comento que no me funciono adjuntare el log que la verdad no muestra nada pero tal vez sirva de referencia